# Filtering rows across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have a tibble with eleven columns and I would like to filter out in ten columns (PC1:PC10) the rows that are not equal to 145.

I have tried to solve this with a for loop. However, this does not work. Is there another option or can somebody explain to me where my error is? I also tried with lapply but I do not know how to integrate the filter function. Thank you very much.

```r
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse) 

set.seed(120)

data.matrix <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=10)
colnames(data.matrix) <- c(
  paste("PC", 1:10, sep=""))
rownames(data.matrix) <- paste("food", 1:100, sep="")
for (i in 1:100) {
  wt.values <- rpois(10, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=1))

  data.matrix[i,] <- c(wt.values)
}
head(data.matrix)
#>       PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 PC6 PC7 PC8 PC9 PC10
#> food1 145 150 136 147 134 158 152 141 152  115
#> food2 629 615 592 636 617 595 618 602 621  626
#> food3 343 355 401 378 361 393 365 374 352  371
#> food4 420 433 417 394 431 430 458 453 404  459
#> food5 866 850 885 826 845 781 838 835 850  857
#> food6  10   7   7  11   7   4   8  11   9   12
dim(data.matrix)
#> [1] 100  10


data <- data.matrix %>% data.frame() %>%  rownames_to_column(var = "food_groups") %>% as_tibble()


# Normally I would do: 

data %>%  filter(!PC1 == 145 ) %>% select(PC1)
data %>%  filter(!PC2 == 145 ) %>% select(PC2)
data %>%  filter(!PC3 == 145 ) %>% select(PC3)

# However, I would like to avoid repetition by looping (or lapply...)

# I tried this and it does not work:

fltr <- function(y) {
  f <- filter(!y == 145) 
  f
}

loadings_final <- function(x) {
  nc <- ncol(x)
  filters <- numeric(nc)
  for (i in 1:nc) {
    filters[i] <- fltr(x[,i])
  }
  filters
}

loadings_final(data)
#> Error in UseMethod("filter_"): nicht anwendbare Methode für 'filter_' auf Objekt der Klasse "c('matrix', 'logical')" angewendet
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: As already noted by others, your task is not as clear as it should be. You state that you "would like to filter out in ten columns (PC1:PC10) the rows that are not equal to 145". Do you mean to filter out the rows **that contain values that are not equal to 145**? If that is what you want then, effectively you would like to keep those rows where the value 145 is found in any of the ten columns, right? If so, that can be accomlished thus: `data.matrix[which(grepl("145", apply(data.matrix, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]`

Comment: Do you want to have 10 separate tibbles as output?

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
data %>% 
melt(., id.vars = "food_groups", measure_vars=c('PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5','PC6','PC7','PC8','PC9','PC10')) %>% 
filter(value != 375)
```

returns:

```
    food_groups variable value
1         food2      PC1    92
2         food3      PC1   801
3         food4      PC1   398
4         food5      PC1   238
5         food6      PC1   213
6         food7      PC1   281
7         food8      PC1  1031 ....
```

You notice that PC1-food1 combination is filtered out.

You can then split this into a list of tibbles:

```
library(reshape2)
data %>% 
melt(., id.vars = "food_groups", measure_vars=c('PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5','PC6','PC7','PC8','PC9','PC10')) %>% 
filter(value != 375) %>% 
group_split(variable) -> mylist
```

After that:

```
# name list elements
names(mylist) <- c('PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5','PC6','PC7','PC8','PC9','PC10')
# assign to global environment
list2env(mylist,globalenv())

# now you have: 
> ls()
 [1] "data"        "data.matrix" "i"           "mylist"      "PC1"
 [6] "PC10"        "PC2"         "PC3"         "PC4"         "PC5"
[11] "PC6"         "PC7"         "PC8"         "PC9"         "wt.values"
```

**Edit:** @Ronak Shah's answer below provides an oneliner approach for generating a list of tibbles split according to PC. After executing his oneliner, you only need to call `list2env()` to get to the desired output. If one likes brevity, his answer is preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I think my example is a little confusing. I will try again: Normally I would simply filter each column as follows to get my desired output, but I'm looking for a way (loop, lapply...) to simplify this and avoid repetition.  


data %>%  filter(!PC1 == 375 ) %>% select(PC1)
data %>%  filter(!PC2 == 375 ) %>% select(PC2)

Comment: The value `145`is found in row #12: `PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 PC6 PC7 PC8 PC9 PC10
food12 161 174 162 148 159 180 140 154 181  145`

Comment: The example uses a function with a randomised output `?sample`. In my draw of `data.matrix`, row 12 is different from yours. @Jzlia10 -- `set.seed()` would have helped.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question above and I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can get list of values using `lapply` :

```
list_output <- lapply(data[-1], function(x) data.frame(col = x[x != 145]))
```

This can also be done with `map`

```
list_output <- purrr::map(data[-1], ~tibble(col = .x[.x != 145]))
```